# Go SMB2 , reading and listing directory

Tags: go, smb

I'm trying to list directory contents on a share from Linux to Windows using Go.
So far I've managed to Create/Remove new files inside a share with full Read/Write permissions.

Go module: https://godoc.org/github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2#Client

Functions:

```
func connect_client(host string, share string, session map[string]string) *smb2.Client {
    //Checks for a connection on port
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":445")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //smb auth
    d := &smb2.Dialer{
        Initiator: &smb2.NTLMInitiator{
            User:     session["Username"],
            Password: session["Password"],
            Domain:   session["Domain"],
        },
    }
    //Returns a client session
    client, err := d.Dial(conn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Connection failed")
        client.Logoff()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Connection Succeeded")
    }
    return client
}

func check_write(host string, client *smb2.Client) {
    file := "asdasdas.txt"
    fs, err := client.Mount(host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    defer fs.Umount()
    share := strings.Split(host, `\\`)
    f, err := fs.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("You do not have write permissions on directory:%s ! \n", strings.Split(share[1], `\`)[1])
        os.Exit(0)

    }
    defer fs.Remove(file)
    defer f.Close()
    fmt.Printf("You have write permissions to directory: %s \n", strings.Split(share[1], `\`)[1]))

}

func list_all(client *smb2.Client, host string) {
    fs, err := client.Mount(host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    defer fs.Umount()

    _, err = fs.Open(`Test.txt`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

}

func main() {
    host, share, action, session := get_flags()
    client := connect_client(host, share, session)
    full_host := `\\` + host + `\` + share

    //File create
    if action == "check_write" {
        check_write(full_host, client)
    }
    if action == "list_files" {
        list_all(client, full_host)
    }

}
```

In the function list_all() everything works, but when I am trying to access \\192.168.1.19\Sharing only..
When I input just a host with directory name it seas it can not list the directory path because it can not find the object specified.
I can't understand how I can get pointer used for *RemoteFile in order to use the functions:

f.Readdir()

f.Name() 
etc....

So far I managed to use *RemoteFileSystem only for all other actions but I want to list all contents of the directory..

Help would be much appreciated!

Edit:
If it wasn't clear enough, in order to use functions like:
f.Readdir() 
f.Name()
I need to get a pointer for *RemoteFile, this is my main issue

Answer (score 0):

https://godoc.org/github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2#RemoteFileSystem.Open

Use Open on a RemoteFileSystem and either a directory name, or empty string for the directory at the root of the filesystem.

e.g.

```
        client, err := d.Dial(conn)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        rfs, err := client.Mount("jrwren")
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        // cat the NOTES file.
        f, err := rfs.Open("NOTES")
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        defer f.Close()
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, f)

        // List all the files
        dir, err := rfs.Open("")
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        fis, err := dir.Readdir(10)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        for i := range fis {
                fmt.Println(fis[i].Name())
        }
```

Comment: thanks alot! what does the fis, err := dir.Readdir(10) int here mean?

Comment: ok so I see that it is the amount of files inside a directory, but how can you just list it all not knowing how many files there are?

Comment: Yes, it is a limit, because directories can be huge. If you want it all, use 0 as the limit.

Comment: is there a way yo list all shares ? by just given an IP address? just like smbclient does?

Answer (score -1):

```
func list_all(client *smb2.Client, host string) {

    fs, err := client.Mount(host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    dir, err := fs.Open("")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    fis, err := dir.Readdir(-1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    for i := range fis {
        fmt.Println(fis[i].Name())
    }
}
```

This would be the answer thank you!